# Polyhedron in $E^n$ with infinitely many sides must contain a side that is a polyhedral wedge

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

So this is from Ratcliffe's text on hyperbolic manifolds. In it there is a part of a proof where he just states that for a polyhedron in $E^n$ with infinitely many sides it must contain a side that is a polyhedral wedge. I don't understand why this is true.

**DEFINITION**: The definition of a polyhedral wedge is a polyhedron such that the intersection of all its sides is nonempty(i.e. think of a triangular wedge in $E^3$ with two planes meeting at a line).

**EDIT**: I've included a copy of the proof in question.
[image]

**EDIT**: Sorry guys. I totally forgot to read all the assumptions in the lemma.

Comment: Yeah, for Ratcliffe he defines a polyhedron so that the collection of sides forms a locally finite collection.

Comment: I wanted to update this question because you did not delete it embarrassing ly but then you did not write out your question ( you referred to a pdf) so now I am conflicted

Comment: It wouldn't let me delete it because there was already an answer, also the question is at the top of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have understood the structure of the argument, which is by contradiction. Suppose $P$ is an *infinite sided* polyhedron so that *all but finitely many sides* of $P$ are wedges. That hypothesis already implies that there is at least **ONE** side which is a polyhedral wedge.

Comment: Oh my, that's a bit embarrassing. I totally forgot about the assumptions in the lemma.

Comment: Should I delete my post or should I keep it up? Ratcliffe's argument is completely fine then. This is my mistake.

Comment: @Enigma That's between you and your God.

Comment: Haha. I might as well keep it up then. A reminder for me to read carefully next time.